# Set the maximum zoom scale on a UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

Is there a way to set the maximum zoom level on a UIImageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think imageviews don't really have the funcionality to zoom, most likely you'll want to slap down a uiscrollview and then insert the imageview as a subview, at that point you'll be able to set the max/min zoom scale on the scrollview. There is an apple sample code project called scrolling that is pretty simple example of scrollviews and imageviews:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html

hope that helps.

nick